# android : Know build info of my application

Tags: android, build

Is there any way to know and show the build version info of my application. I can get version of my app. I want to know on which platform was my app build i.e. 1.6, 2.1 etc. "Build.VERSION.RELEASE" gives me the build of the device. Similarly I want build of my application regardless of the device info.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this information from `PackageManager` and [`getPackageInfo()`](http://goo.gl/AQox1).

Comment: From getPackageInfo(), I lloked at it good enough, but didn't find any method that could give me such a response. I can get the target SDK i.e. minSDK set in manifest, but not on which it is actually built. Like the minSDK might be 4, but I might had built it in 7, I want to retrieve info 7. How can I get that ?

Comment: @Tvd: AFAIK, that is not supported. You are welcome to bake that information into your app yourself (e.g., integer resource).